# I want to try product variant weight according to mrp show with react js ,but didn't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I wanted to try product variant weight according to MRP show with react js, but it didn't work. please suggest me. I want to pass onChange() product variants weight mannualy its worked, but I want to pass value use  e.target.value did not work. how do I do?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const product = {
    productName: "IndoPrimo Men's Regular Fit Cotton Casual Shirt",
    productCategory: "HUMJOLI",
    image: "../images/I/71ZFayjCD-L._UL1500_.jpg",
    maxQty: 5,
    minQty: 1,
    unit: "gram",
    variantNames: ["weight"],
    variants: [
      { weight: 500, mrp: 100, storePrice: 80 },
      { weight: 1000, mrp: 200, storePrice: 140 },
    ],
    productMrp: 2199,
    productStoreprice: 7189,
  };
  const [sate, setSize] = React.useState([]);
  const handleBtn = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.value;
    console.log(id);
    const updatei̥tem = product.variants.filter((r) => {
      return r.weight === id;
    });
    setSize(updatei̥tem);
   
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select name="r" onChange={(e) => handleBtn(e)}>
        {product.variants.map((i) => (
          <option value={i.weight} key={i.weight}>
            {i.weight}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      
      <div>
        {sate?.map((i) => (
          <p>{i.mrp}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *strict* equality operator `===` in the filter function is *too* strict for you case. `r.weight` is a `number`, and `id` is a `string`.

You can change it to `==`, then the type casting will be done automatically:

```
const updatei̥tem = product.variants.filter((r) => {
      return r.weight == id;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Data() {
  const product = {
    productName: "IndoPrimo Men's Regular Fit Cotton Casual Shirt",
    productCategory: "HUMJOLI",
    image: "../images/I/71ZFayjCD-L._UL1500_.jpg",
    maxQty: 5,
    minQty: 1,
    unit: "gram",
    variantNames: ["weight"],
    variants: [
      { weight: 500, mrp: 100, storePrice: 80 },
      { weight: 1000, mrp: 200, storePrice: 140 },
    ],
    productMrp: 2199,
    productStoreprice: 7189,
  };
  const [sate, setSize] = useState([]);
  const handleBtn = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.value;

    /*Suggestion 1*/

    const updatei̥tem = product.variants.filter((r) => {
      if (r.weight === +id) {
        return r;
      }
    });
    setSize(updatei̥tem);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select name="r" onChange={(e) => handleBtn(e)}>
        {product.variants.map((i) => (
          <option value={i.weight} key={i.weight}>
            {i.weight}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      {/*Suggestion 2*/}

      {sate &&
        sate.map((i) => {
          return <p>{i.weight}</p>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Data;

My suggestions, I hope it works
```